# Swift closure generic parameters

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I have a protocol defined as

```
func get<T: ApiModel, TError: ApiModel>(url: String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:(T)->Void, error:(TError?, NSError)->Void) -> Void;
```

Trying to call it as

```
self.webClient.get("http://google.com", params: nil, headers:      headers, success: { (response: ConcreteClass) in

        }, error: { (errorModel:ConcreteErrorClass, error: NSError) in

    })
```

This results in the following error:

```
'Cannot convert value of type (ConcreteClass) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> Void'
```

Comment: The first parameter of the error closure must be optional according to the declaration (`TError?`).

Comment: Annoyingly it didn't highlight the failure closure as the problem. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration of the method you're calling, the `error:` closure has the first parameter of optional type (`error:(TError?, NSError)->Void`), but you declared it with non-optional type. That may be the reason (indeed, Swift sometimes produces pretty unrelated error messages).